# Finding top values with criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to extract a sorted list of the top 15 technologies from my data sheet in category 1. I have a data sheet with the below structure:

```
Technologies   Category  Score
  Tech 1          1       35
  Tech 2          3       59
  Tech 3          5       26
  Tech 4          3       76
  Tech 5          1       28
  Tech 6          1       0
  Tech 7          1       35
    ...          ...      ...
```

I have tried Index Match with Large & IF, but it didn’t give the right result; I got duplicate technology results, and I figured out that because I have duplicate scores, the result I get is Tech 1, Tech 1, Tech 5 which rather should be Tech 1, Tech 7, Tech 5. I also tried Sort, Filter combination with Large, which didn’t work, I get Value error with it:

```
=SORT(FILTER('Data Sheet'!G2:G126;('Data Sheet'!L2:L126>=LARGE(IF('Data Sheet'!K2:K126=1;'Data Sheet'!L$2:L126);15))*('Data Sheet'!K2:K126=1));15;-1)
```

I also would like to exclude if I reach values 0 in my top 15. Any suggestions how to fix the formula and include this additional aspect?

Comment: Please provide a data set that includes the duplicate scores, e.g. for Tech1 - then it is easier to test the formulas. And if you provide a expected result set for that data set - it makes it much easier to help you

Comment: Thanks, Ike, the data I show in the table already has the indication of a duplicate score, e.g. Tech 1 and Tech 7 in category 1 both have a score of 35.  And I indicated that the result I should get in the above case would be Tech 1 (35), Tech 7 (35), Tech 5 (28). Or do you mean something else here?

Comment: But what about "Tech 1, Tech 1, Tech 5"  -- this looks like if there would be two Techt 1 on the the list ...

Comment: Ah, no sorry, that was the result I got when I used the index match formula, which was the issue; I only have all individual technologies in my list but returned result from Index Match was duplicates of the same technologies, I thought because I didn't have all unique scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this formula fit your needs:

`=TAKE(SORT(FILTER(tblData,(tblData[Category]=1)*(tblData[Score]<>0)),3,-1),15)`

You will need the current channel of Excel 365 - due to the `TAKE` function

[image]

**UPDATE**:
Using your setup you will need this formula:

`= TAKE(SORT(FILTER('Data Sheet'!G2:L41,('Data Sheet'!K2:K41=1)*('Data Sheet'!L2:L41<>0)),6,-1),15,1)`

Comment: If OP doesn't have access to `TAKE()` function then can use `INDEX()` and `SEQUENCE()` function.

Comment: Thanks, Ike; I used the formula with a little modification since I want to extract only the tech list without category and score, and my data-sheet is not an excel table, I modified it to: 

`=TAKE(SORT(FILTER('Data Sheet'!G2:G200;('Data Sheet'!K2:K200=1)*('Data Sheet'!L2:L200<>0));3;-1);15) `
But I get a value error; not sure if because of the current channel thing (I use O365) or because I am doing something wrong in modification.

Comment: do you get `TAKE` in the formula drop down when typing a `=`?

Comment: Your modification won't work: you select only one column, but want to sort by column 3. You have to use the the range from G:L to be able to sort by Score. I updated my answer accordingly.